# Review error with Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: html, microdata, google-search-console, microformats, rich-snippets

why Google Structured Data Testing Tool says that "No rich snippet will be generated for this data, because it appears to include multiple reviews of an item, but no aggregate review information"

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamempire.it%2Fcastlestorm-ps-vita%2Frecensione%2F131419

This is the code of the page: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7675765, that you can find here: http://www.gamempire.it/castlestorm-ps-vita/recensione/131419

Thanks

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML in the question.

Comment: the relevant markup is in the question

Comment: @unor to solve the problem it's necessary to watch all the html source of the page to discover the problem, because it affects all the page.

Comment: @OscarFanelli: [Here again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224219/author-error-inside-google-structured-data-test?noredirect=1#comment30189997_20224219): It’s good to add a link to the page; but you should include the relevant HTML in your question, too, because the link might go 404 in the future. Then this question would be of absolutely no use to anyone.

Comment: @unor you are right, I have added a gist

Answer (score 2):

Oscar, your page has both the hreview and review schema markups.  So to Google, it looks like you have two different reviews on your page.  You should use only one vocabulary for the review.  I would suggest schema.  In the event that your page has more than one review or rating, you would then also need to use the aggregate rating schema as well.

Comment: what shema do you suggest? review or hreview? google suggest hreview: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=it&ref_topic=1088474

Comment: strange, now the tool says: "Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org."

Comment: I definitely recommend schema, as this is endorsed by all three major search engines, and you can specifically define more elements with it.  The examples that Google is showing are somewhat outdated.