# Author error inside Google Structured Data Test

Tags: html, microdata, google-search-console, microformats, rich-snippets

I receive this error when analyzing a review of my website: "Missing required hCard "author""

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamempire.it%2Fcastlestorm-ps-vita%2Frecensione%2F131419

Why? I have setted the class="author" inside the html.

This is the code of the page: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7675765, that you can find here: http://www.gamempire.it/castlestorm-ps-vita/recensione/131419

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML in the question.

Comment: its in the question....the url being asked about is in the richsnippets url

Comment: @unor exactly as albert says

Comment: @albert: The link might die. Then all the answers are of no use to anyone else, as the code in question is missing. Also, the linked page might change, which would be confusing when several answers are about *different* code.

Comment: @unor added, like in the other question :) thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

`author vcard` has to be inside the `hentry` element http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry or you have to use the `include pattern` http://microformats.org/wiki/include-pattern, but I am not sure if it is supported by Google...

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring author a few times in that document...not sure if you want to use microformats, schema.org, or both?

you have markup for both, and one of the author classes is actually nested inside the other...so at the very least that is not correct....fix your nested authors first. if that doesn't resolve validation, come back and share. the solution(s) are relatively easy, but impossible to give you the correct one without knowing more.

Comment: I have a `<address class="vcard author">` and inside it a `<a class="fn url" itemprop="author">`: do I have to remove the `itemprop` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a new user mentioning him as Author in Admin Access, then open a page and go to screen option and select author. Now in the page check for author and update it with the new author user which you already created.